# Best way to relate foreign key to parent

Tags: mysql

I don't dabble much in SQL design at all, so this might be a trivial question.

I have a `players` table:

```
CREATE TABLE players(
    p_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    p_name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL 
)
```

I have a `results` table:

```
CREATE TABLE results(

    f_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    f_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    p1_id INT NULL,
    p2_id INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (p1_id) REFERENCES players(p_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (p2_id) REFERENCES players(p_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
)
```

When I add an `INSERT` into the `results` table, I am adding the `p1_id` and `p2_id`. For this to work, I need to already have these id's defined in the `players` table, with the accompanying string name for this id. Programmatically, what should I do with my data before adding to the `results` table?

1. Check if `p_id` exists (from my `p1_id` and `p2_id` values), if not, `INSERT` them with the accompanying string.
2. Add my data into the results table as a normal insert

Or is there a more conventional way to do these things? Maybe some SQL quirk i'm not aware of?

Comment: Where would you get your p1_id / p2_id values if not from the main players table in the first place? Plus, your FKs ensure that you cannot insert a non-existent player id in the two player fields, so no separate checks are necessary.

Comment: *Check if p_id exists (from my p1_id and p2_id values), if not, INSERT them with the accompanying string.* No. Define `p_id` column as unique (even primary key). Then insert into `players` unconditionally, without any checking, using INSERT IGNORE - after this the value is present in the table anycase. Now insert into `results`.